# Is a PSN account required to transfer data from PS4 to PS5?

Tags: ps4, ps5

I just got a PS5, and I'm trying to transfer my data over from my PS4. I transferred the data from the one user with a PSN account just fine, but now I want to transfer my saved data from a user without a PSN account. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer your PS4 save data via USB to PS5. Connect a USB storage device to your PS4 and go to Settings > Application Saved Data Management > Saved Data in System Storage > Copy to USB Storage Device. Select the save file you'd like to copy, and you can transfer it to the USB drive

### SOURCE

[1]https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-transfer-ps4-save-data-to-ps5
[2]https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/support/hardware/transfer-games-saved-data-ps4-ps5/